# How to find where a built-in program/command is defined in Stata?

Tags: stata

If I want to find where a built-in program/command in Stata (e.g. `generate`) is defined and/or being loaded from, is there a way to query an interactive Stata session to find out?  Or do I have to search through `adopath` to find it?

I'm especially curious about `generate`, because there doesn't seem to be a .ado file for it in `adopath`, though there are other similar types of files.

Comment: If a Stata command is called built-in, that means it is not defined by an ado and the code is proprietary.

Comment: When I say "built-in" I mean "provided in the base Stata installation."  I didn't know "built-in" was a specific technical term, and I don't know how to tell whether it applies to a command or not.

Comment: Type “which generate” to see Stata exemplify its own use of the term. Commands included in the Stata you download are called “official”. Most are defined by ado files.

Comment: Crud, I was going to make my own copy and modify `generate`, but it looks built-in.

Comment: Not only looks, but is.  There is plenty of scope to create variables otherwise e.g. through Mata.  More advice would need to be built on quite what you want to do (and even why).